# Is the weak convergence of a sequence unique?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n\overset{w}{\to}X$, if there exist a $Y\neq X$ such that $X_n\overset{w}{\to}Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Only the distribution of $X$ is unique. If $Y$ is another random variable with the same distribution as $X$ then we certainly have $X _n \to Y$ weakly.

For example let $X$ have standard normal distribution. Let $X_n =X$ for all $n$. Then $X_n \to X$ and $x_n \to -X$ weakly!